# PDF to HTML Conversion API - Best Option using C#

Tags: c#, html, pdf

I would like the best way and method to convert from PDF to HTML, Note the PDFs contain different layouts, smart arts, images. Can you please suggest? I would actually prefer an API which I can use in a C# program and thus programmatically convert a number of files. I would prefer converting the images and embed them as base64 itself

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago (2013), I developed a PDF to epub (a variation of HTML) converter.

I also wanted to develop in C# and looked what was available, but the best libraries are in C/C++. You probably know that PDF is a very tricky format, and even the best converters fail on some documents, so you really have to stick with the best options.

From C#, you can easily call C or C++ functions, so using a library in those languages is not be much of a problem.

Poppler http://poppler.freedesktop.org/ is the PDF library that I chose:  It is based on Xpdf PDF viewer. It is reliable but you will have to postprocess the HTML code anyway. This package contains command line utilities including pdftohtml, a PDF to HTML converter. Sources files are also available.

Another very good option is PDFLib: http://www.pdflib.com/ It is a commercial product.